# How to Uninstall Nokia Connectivity Framework (NCF?) - Cannot Install Nokia SDK 1.0 for Java

Tags: java-me, sdk, symbian, nokia

My first attempt at installing Nokia SDK 1.0 for Java failed due to Avira AntiVir detected a malware on it, so I had to "ignore" the Malware and cancel the installation (which it seemed to not undoing it properly) and restart installation.

However the next installation failed while giving the following message:

> Nokia Connectivity Framework(NCF) is already installed. Please uninstall NCF and press 'Ok' to proceed with installation.

At this point I am stuck. I've deleted the C:\Nokia\Tools folder entirely, and I can't find the "Nokia Connectivity Framework (NCF)" entry on "Add Remove Programs. There's not even a Cancel button (to close the installer) or Override button on this dialog box. Quite annoying. :-(

If you have a solution for this problem, please help.

(originally blogged at http://qt-mobile.posterous.com/how-to-uninstall-nokia-connectivity-framework )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used regedit.exe to find key :

```
Connectivity_Framework
```

You will find something like :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Nokia\Connectivity_Framework
```

Change it to :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Nokia\Connectivity_Framework_no_longer
```

(you can undo by renaming it back, if needed)

Then just press ok, or try installing again.

I have done this on 2 computers : one running vista and the other running windows 7.